# CSS Centering to part of page length

Tags: html

So what I thought was going to be simple has turned out to be quite challenging for some reason. Basically my challenge here is that I have text that needs to be the same format when expanded as it is while in a smaller window. While it is in the smaller window it is perfectly centered but when expanded it has way too much space to the right.

I have followed the directions on a different post saying to set it to a fixed position and then set the margins to auto but I now am seeing that there isn't a "min-margin-right.

```
<div style = 'position: fixed; z-index:4; left: 0; right: 0; top:80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%; font-style: Courier; font-weight: bold; font-size: 25px;'>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Conquerer's Quest</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:-3;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
  <img src='space.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
</div>
<!-- main game box -->
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:2%;top:3%;width:80%;height:75%; background-color: #900; border: 5px double black'>
 <canvas id = gameCanvas> 
 </canvas>
</div>
<!-- descriptions box -->
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:1;left:2%;top:78.5%;width:80%;height:20%; background-color: #656060;  border: 5px double black'>
 <canvas id = instructionsCanvas> 
 </canvas>
</div>
<!-- description header -->

<div style = 'position: fixed; z-index:4; left: 0; right: 0; top:80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%; font-style: Courier; font-weight: bold; font-size: 25px;'>

<u align = "center">
  Conquerer's Quest Summary
  </u>
</div>
<!-- description text -->
<div style = 'position:absolute; z-index:4;top:82%;left:5%;right: 20%; font-style: Courier;font-weight: small; font-size: 21px;'>
<p align="center">
  <p1>Conquerer's Quests is an RPG following the adventures of you the player. You can choose between several classes including the swordsman, the assassain, the knight, the wizard, and the ranger. The main objective of the game is to locate and get into the Conquerer's Sanctuary but along the way the player can level up their character, sell and buy armor and weapons, and complete side quests.</p1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just use `text-align: center`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge gave the already!

Comment: @ObsidianAge Im trying to center a small line of text so it does not stretch all the way across the page. The margin on the right is still massive when I tried to use center align. I imagine this is because I'm not centering around the page I'm centering around a part of the page. Unless I'm not using that correctly

Comment: @Md.SifatulIslam Gave the what already?

Comment: If your margins are incorrect with `text-align: center`, the problem is with your margins, not the centralisation of the text ;)

Comment: @ObsidianAge well then damn im seriously screwed up with margins then. I tried removing margins, setting both to auto, changing both to 50%, and then of course what I have it as in the code that I listed above. Want the src code? Its somewhat hard to understand the possible stupidity im spitting.

Comment: The full relevant HTML and CSS would certainly help. Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and for further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: will do. Should be good now hopefully

Comment: @NateCraft gave the answer already!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working for me—at least as far as horizontal centering is concerned. What browser are you using? Perhaps that is the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Im using chrome so it shouldnt be too much of a problem... In my browser its centered in a smaller window but not in the expanded. I can supply the entire html doc (just started so its not too long w/ any extra scripts) so you can see what im getting at here.

Comment: No offense, but this layout is kind of a mess. I'd recommend taking a look at using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to redo your layout.

Comment: oh no offense taken. I knew it was a mess when I wrote it lol